# adjust font of *中文* word in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I'm using `PingFang SC` for Chinese characters in spacemacs

```
   dotspacemacs-default-font '(("Fira Code"
                            :size 14
                            :weight normal
                            :width normal
                            :powerline-scale 1.1)
                           ("PingFang SC"
                            :size 14
                            :weight normal
                            :width normal
                            :powerline-scale 1.1))
```

in org-mode, the normal Chinese character is displayed with the right font

```
             position: 6042 of 9361 (65%), column: 3
        character: 文 (displayed as 文) (codepoint 25991, #o62607, #x6587)
preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x6587
           script: han
           syntax: w    which means: word
         category: .:Base, C:2-byte han, L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese, h:Korean, j:Japanese, |:line breakable
         to input: type "C-x 8 RET 6587"
      buffer code: #xE6 #x96 #x87
        file code: #xE6 #x96 #x87 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
          display: by this font (glyph code)
mac-ct:-*-PingFang SC-normal-normal-normal-*-14-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1 (#xDC8)
```

but bolded one *文* fall to another font,

```
             position: 6046 of 9361 (65%), column: 3
        character: 文 (displayed as 文) (codepoint 25991, #o62607, #x6587)
preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x6587
           script: han
           syntax: w    which means: word
         category: .:Base, C:2-byte han, L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese, h:Korean, j:Japanese, |:line breakable
         to input: type "C-x 8 RET 6587"
      buffer code: #xE6 #x96 #x87
        file code: #xE6 #x96 #x87 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
          display: by this font (glyph code)
mac-ct:-*-Arial Unicode MS-bold-normal-normal-*-14-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1 (#x3816)
```

how to control this?

Comment: Normally, bold fonts are separate. Try adding both a normal weight and a bold font.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 specifically how? append bold font to dotspacemacs-default-font? tried but not work. FYI, I once config font with variable-pitch-mode and set variable-pitch to "Ping Fang SC", in that way bold chinese character is using the right font.

Comment: Try removing `:weight normal` from the definition of that font in your init file. I don't know how exactly how spacemacs handles this.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Thanks for your help, but that doesn't work either.