# Is it possible to change font size only for Chinese characters in Org tables?

Tags: org-mode, fonts, faces

I want to use different fonts for different languages, for example, Consolas for Latin characters and Microsoft YaHei for Chinese characters. I can do this by `M-x customize-face RET default` and changing the default fontset for `han` script specifically:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'han (font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 15))
```

However, this will affect all Chinese characters everywhere. I want to use a different size for Chinese characters in Org tables. After much researching I tried creating a fontset for the `org-table` face's font family as it is said in `info:elisp#Fontsets` that you can use a fontset name in place of a font name when you specify the font for a frame or a face. So this should be done by running the following:

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec "-outline-Consolas-normal-normal-normal-mono-15-*-*-*-c-*-fontset-orgtable")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-orgtable" 'han (font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 16))
```

Then `M-x customize-face RET org-table`. Change the Font Family field to `fontset-orgtable`. But this doesn't work. Or maybe it's due to my misunderstanding of how to create and use a fontset. So what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: based on this question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41424/adjust-font-of-%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-word-in-org-mode it seems you should be able to change font size per font, and in my case my chinese characters seem to use a different font (do M-x what-cursor-position C-u RET), but I don't know how to set font specifically for the given font, which for me is `-GOOG-Noto Sans CJK KR-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1`

Comment: it may be worth investigating https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+intl/chinese/README.html as well but it doesn't seem to do what i want